# VS 2015 breaks code using CLOCKS_PER_SEC in preprocessos

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

I am porting my old codebase to VS 2015.
The code is :

```
#if XYZ 
  ....
#elif CLOCKS_PER_SEC > 999 //<< Getting error here.
  ...
#endif
```

I am getting error in line `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` :

```
Severity    Code    Description 
Error       C1012   unmatched parenthesis: missing ')'
```

Looking at definition of `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` in `time.h`

```
// The number of clock ticks per second
#define CLOCKS_PER_SEC  ((clock_t)1000)
```

So, it looks like it is because of `clock_t` as pre-processor macros can not work with that.

Please suggest how can i fix it ?

Comment: you have got some weird library issue, `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is defined as constant value (1000) without the `clock_t` conversion in my version of time.h. You probably should re-install your entire dev environment.

Comment: CLOCKS_PER_SEC was defined as 1000 prior to VS2015.  Can you add a condition to check the version of the compiler?

Comment: `c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\time.h` is the name of `time.h` file.

Comment: @specializt: There's nothing "weird" in `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` being defined in some other way. Nobody promised you that it shall be defined as `(1000)` forever. In fact, `(1000)` is an invalid definition. The language spec requires it to have `clock_t` type, not `int` type.

Comment: `clocks_per_sec` is listed as a breaking change in windows docs : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx

Comment: @AnT that may be some **weird** UNIX spec but it certainly is no MSVC spec - UNIX or possibly even POSIX specifications do not apply to this question. At all.

Comment: @specializt: I'm talking exclusively about the *language* spec, i.e. *C language standard*, not about UNIX, POSIX or MSVC. Indeed, they do not apply to this question.

Comment: MSVC / MSVC++ does not (fully) implement the the _C language standard_. You should've known that by now. This major difference is the main reason for OSS programmers (somewhat) failing, once they try to apply non-microsoft standards with microsoft tools. I have read about the claim that MSVC follows standards - it is simply wrong. Some people will not admit it, even if confronted with hard facts _(not talking about you, of course)_

Comment: @specializt: Wrong. MSVC 2015 does fully implement C99 language standard. As any other compiler, it has some *deviations* from it (bugs), but these are minor localized issues (which, again, exist in any compiler). However, this is irrelevant in the context of this question anyway, since the observed behavior is perfectly standard. In fact, the problem with `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is related to a *defect in C99 standard*, not to some issue in MSVC compiler.  The original C99 standard was defective in its definition of `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. The defect was fixed in one of the later TCs to C99.

Comment: Here's the link to the official defect report: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_281.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C language specification states in 7.1.4/1 that

> All object-like macros listed as expanding to integer constant
>   expressions shall additionally be suitable for use in #if
>   preprocessing directives.

However, macro `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is not listed as integer constant expression (7.27.1/2). This means that it cannot be portably used under `#if`.

This is exactly what you just ran into. You should develop an alternative way to implement conditional compilation in your code. In general case `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` cannot be used with `#if`. The language standard requires `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to have `clock_t` type, not `int` type, which means that the cast is perfectly justified there.

**P.S.** Note that your current definition of `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` *does* qualify as integral constant expression, but `#if` imposes some additional requirements on the conditional expression. Namely, casts are not allowed.

**P.P.S.** In the original version of C99, `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` was described as a *constant* expression. However, in C99+TC2 the word "constant" is no longer there. It was removed in order to eliminate the contradiction between the aforementioned requirements: 1) constant expression macros being usable under `#if`, which precludes casts, and 2) `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` having `clock_t` type, which is only achievable through a cast. The corresponding defect report can be found here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_281.htm

Comment: by `expanding to integer constant expressions` you mean that any macros final expansion would be a integer value like `1000`.. ?

Comment: any suggestions for "alternative ways".. Would there be anything better than overriding global `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` ? in that place, would it be possible to add templates to give errors at compile time if my overridden value 1000 deviates from future changes in time.h ?

Comment: otherwise i can change the preprocessor state to compile time check .. i.e. chaing  `#elif` to `if` condition.

Comment: It's not so much that casts are not allowed (although they indeed aren't), it's that after expansion, the syntax doesn't leave any cast. `((clock_t)1000)` gets preprocessed to `((0)1000)` because the preprocessor doesn't know anything about typedefs. `((0)1000)` is a syntax error.